# CSS Drop Down Menu on iPhone / iPad - can't click links

Tags: css, mobile, drop-down-menu

I use a css-drop-down menu on the following site: 
[Website](http://www.precimo.de/index.php/qualitaet)

You can test the menu at the top menu-items. 
On desktop everything works fine. But on iPhone or iPad not. 
There you can click on one of the top menu-items. Then the drop down menu opens without problems. But if I click on one of the links in the drop down menu nothing happens.

This is the css-code for the drop down menu:

```
#mainmenu ul li > ul {
    display: none;
    top: 0px;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover  > ul,
#mainmenu ul li:active > ul,
#mainmenu ul li:focus  > ul,
#mainmenu ul li > a#aktuell + ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Do you have an idea why not?

Comment: How is the drop down triggered, if it is triggered using hover selector, In ipad or iphone click event is equivalent to click and hover, so the drop down will not work

Comment: I have added code. I tried to use :hover, :active and :focus.
But nothing works

Comment: As i told you click event is equivalent to click, hover, focus so nothing will work try my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thats the solution

```
$('#menu li ul li a').bind('touchstart', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        location.href = href;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the drop down menu is triggered via the hover event. As I said earlier with the comment, in touch devices a click event is equivalent to click and hover, so it will not work directly.

If the hover menu item does not have a link, solution is:

1. Import modernizer to your code: http://modernizr.com/
2. Convert the hover to double tap via JavaScript:

   $('.mainmenu').doubleTap(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('hover');
   });
3. Add `class="mainmenu"` to the list item

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but this don't work for me.
I have integrated the modernizr, jquery and the javascript and added the class "mainmenu" to the ul-tag of the menu

Comment: add the class to the list item that has hover event

Comment: Did you check the other answer

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript Solution**

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var els= nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    els[i].addEventListener(’touchstart’, function(){this.className = “hover”;}, false);
    els[i].addEventListener(’touchend’, function(){this.className = “”;}, false);
```

where nav is the id of the div that holds the memu

**Jquery Solution**

```
$('#nav li').bind('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}).bind('touchend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

**CSS**

```
li:hover, li.hover { /* whatever your hover effect is */ }
```

Hope this works

Comment: OK I tried this solution with jquery. 
I have integrated this code (but changed #nav to .menu).
And i have added the li.hover to the line where the drop down menu gets visible (#mainmenu ul li:hover>ul, #mainmenu ul li>a#aktuell+ul,  #mainmenu ul li.hover>u).

But no success - same error again.

Comment: Ok, let's see if there are any other solution

Comment: OK now I have created a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fomlackner/hyFWP/. And I just tested this fiddle on my iphone - and there it works :( ... ist the layout of the website wrong? or the divs?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a try. Try to put in "< a > tags" the code below

```
onClick=”return true”
```

It's simple and it was what worked for me.